# AMD GPU is not working on Kdenlive for Rendering Videos

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon, kdenlive

I am trying to use **Kdenlive** on my Windows 10 laptop that has **AMD GPU R5 M330, 2 GB**.

When I export a video, it just doesn't use it. Only CPU is being used which is really really slow even for 2-minute video.

When I choose AMD option in the rendering dialog, it says:

```
Unsupported video codec: h264_vaapi
```

[image]

Do I have to install anything else to make it work?

I have googled it already but couldn't find anything that seems helpful.

Comment: vaapi is not available on Windows. You should try amf instead, if the ffmpeg build you have is built with the support.

Comment: @TomYan And amf is already installed or I have to download something extra. I mean I have AMD Station installed already.

Comment: What I meant was, you should look for some "AMF encoder" (or "AMD encoder" that has no irrelevant wording like "vaapi"; I don't know how the option would be shown) on the list in you shown on the screenshot. If there's no such choice available, then likely the ffmpeg kdenlive ships is not built with AMF support (or, kdenlive hasn't got the support to make use of it in its own code yet). Obviously whether you have installed the required drivers or libraries does not matter, otherwise you won't see all the choices that are irrelevant on the list.

Comment: By the way, I suppose you are using a native version of kdenlive (instead of some WSL version), right?

Comment: Yes it has `h264amf` when i create a custom rendering profile from here https://www.pling.com/p/1893905. I checked that FFmpeg that Kdenlive is using has the same encoder enabled. But it is still not rendering, giving errors: https://res.cloudinary.com/suleman/image/upload/v1673809933/error.png

Comment: Yes it's Windows version not WSL.

Comment: No idea. Maybe you can ask [here](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF/issues). You are [not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74216907) anyway.